# Using "or" ,"and", "like" several times in same column

Tags: mysql, sql-like

If I have a table like this:

```
id     car
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
2       A
2       B
2       C
2       F
3       A
3       C
3       E
3       F
3       G
```

what I want is different "id" which have `("A" or "C") and "B"` in `car`. For example:

```
id    car
1      A
1      B
1      C
2      A
2      B
2      C
```

what I did was

```
select * from table where (car like "A" or car like"C") and (car like "B")
```

but it gives me an empty row.

Any clue?

Comment: You're looking for two different values of `car` in the **same** row. That's not possible.

Comment: use or : `select * from table where car like "A" or car like"C" or car like "B"`

Comment: @Barmar then what should I do?

Comment: @SardorDushamov ur code will give

    id    car
    1      A
    1      B
    1      C
    2      A
    2      B
    2      C
    3      A
    3      B

 right?

Comment: you may try this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.car IN ('A', 'C')
AND t2.car = 'B'
```

BTW, you should generally only use `LIKE` when you're doing a pattern match. For exact matches use `=`, or `IN` for matching any of multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like this should work: get all rows that have the ID such that it is found on the list of all IDs that have an A or a C, and also on the list of all IDs that have a B.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM mytable t2
  WHERE t2.car='A' OR t2.car='C'
)
AND t.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM mytable t3
  WHERE t3.car='B'
)
```